# I'm receiving an uncaught type Error when looping using .add() in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

Once I have rendered my template with my  elements I wanted to add options with values dynamically from JSON data, it populates and works fine but gives me: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: sel.add is not a function

I have tried and failed to use a different set-up with .appendChild and it's doing me. I can't see the issue but I haven't been using JS long enough to know hope someone can help.

```
...js

const csv = require('csvtojson');
const path = "filepath here";

readData(path);

async function readData(path){
    const data = await csv().fromFile(path).on('header', (header) =>{
        assign(header);
    });
}


function assign(col){
//Renders Template
    const contain = document.getElementById("container");
    const temp = document.getElementById("dropdown").content;
    const clone = temp.cloneNode(true);
    contain.appendChild(clone);
    populate(col);
}

function populate(col){
    //Populates dropdown boxes with data from headers
    const group = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
    for(let i in group){
        for(let x in col){
           let sel = document.getElementsByClassName('choice')[i];
           let opt = document.createElement('option');
           opt.text = col[x];
           opt.value = col[x];
           sel.add(opt, sel[x]);
       }

   }

}

...

...html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Bulk Upload Assistant</title>
</head>
    <body> 
        <div id="container">
                <h1>Please browse to upload file</h1>
                <input type="button"  id = "browse-files" value="Browse" >

                <template id="dropdown">
                  <p>Please select the appropriate headings for your file</p>
                        <p class = "drop-down">ID field</p>
                        <p class = "drop-down">Leaver field</p>
                        <p class = "drop-down">Auth Type field</p>

                            <select id="ID" class = "choice">
                            </select>
                            <select id="LEAVE" class = "choice">
                            </select>
                            <select id="AUTH" class = "choice">   
                            </select>
                        <button onClick = 'getHeadings()'>Submit</button> 
                </template>

        </div>



        <script src = 'render.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>

...
```

Should not throw the error message

Comment: What do you expect `.add()` to do? `sel` is an HTML element, and HTML elements don't have an `.add()` method. Did you mean to use `appendChild()`? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: The .add() method is to append items to a select drop down, getting the same error with appendChild() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp

Comment: Can you confirm `sel` is the element you think it is? You should add `console.log(sel)` after creating its variable reference.

Comment: console.log(sel) returns the <select> element, there are 3 in total. The error only occurs after exiting both loops as all my elements are populated with the correct data from the array.

Comment: This has now been resolved, turns out it was a previous `async` function causing the issue. Thanks anyway :)